# whats wrong with my arduino code? I get a failure to compile error and not sure why

Tags: arduino

This program regulates an electric motor telling it before3 seconds to output 120 volts and after 3 seconds to output 255 volts.. Not sure why this isn't compiling.

```
int motorPin = 9;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    #include <time.h>

    if ( int tm_sec<int tm_3sec);
    analogWrite(9,120);

    else ( int tm_sec>int tm_3sec);
    analogWrite(9,255);
```

Comment: You should move the `include` statement out of the `loop()` function. Also remove semicolons after `if`s. Aslo, declare `tm_sec`....lots of issues.

Comment: The #include is out of place in loop().

Comment: Please actually include your compiler output

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems. First, the `include` directive replaces that line of code with the entire file and are usually placed at the beginning of the source code file. Plus, this is Arduino. Use `millis()` instead.

```
const int motorPin = 9;

void setup() {
    pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // millis() resets to 0 when the Arduino resets
    if (millis() < 3000) {
        analogWrite(motorPin, 120);
    }
    else {
        analogWrite(motorPin, 255);
    }
}
```

However, this will not output 120V and 255V. The Arduino can't do that. `analogWrite` writes a PWM signal based on the value you send it. You should read this: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/analogWrite